# Can a treatment have a significant effect on the sum but insignificant effect on its parts?

Tags: statistical-significance, permutation-test

Using approximate randomization test, I show that my randomized treatment has a positive and significant effect on an aggregate index $Y_s$, which is the sum of 4 individual indices, i.e.

$$Y_s = Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 + Y_4$$

Surprisingly, my treatment has positive but *insignificant* on each of these 4 constituent indices.

What may be the cause? I especially don't know how to approach this in the framework of a randomization test (where there's no formula for the standard error of the estimate to build off).

Comment: If the $Y_i$ variables are positively correlated, this isn't surprising, but is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is in the observation that *each* $Y_i$ was impacted by the treatment, which is surprising even if the effect on any given one appears small.

To illustrate the basic idea take the toy example where each $Y_i$ is either equal to $1$ or $-1$ with equal probability.  It's not at all interesting when any $Y_i$ equals one, but it *is* interesting when $Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 + Y_4 = 4$.  Essentially the sum is measuring something which the individual components cannot, and that is the cumulative or overall effect of the treatment.

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160496/is-re-randomization-valid-approach-to-estimate-statistical-significance) is a related question that touches on these ideas.